# Synchronizing qgsofflineediting database data back to remote layers using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, editing, pyqgis-3, geopackage, offline

I have a situation where I need to find the `path(database)` of GeoPackage, if the path has already exist then I need to use the existing GeoPackage data to load the offline data using `qgsofflineediting` API and synchronize the data back to remote layer using the object.

Below, I have used the code to load the *.gpkg* layers and its style. But my question is how I will insatiate the object reference of the offline database, so that when I will call the synchronize method it will push the local database changes to remote layers.

```py
self.offline_editing = QgsOfflineEditing()
offline_data_path = QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath()

file_name = olt_name+".gpkg"
gpkg_file_path = os.path.join(offline_data_path, file_name)

if os.path.exists(gpkg_file_path):
   # get the path to a geopackage  e.g. /usr/share/qgis/resources/data/world_map.gpkg
   path_to_gpkg = gpkg_file_path
   gpkg_layers = [l.GetName() for l in ogr.Open(path_to_gpkg) if 'log' not in l.GetName()]
   for lyr in gpkg_layers:
       split_name = lyr.split("_")[0]
       print(split_name)
       qml_file_path = self.db_obj.get_style(split_name)

       styledoc = QDomDocument()
       styledoc.setContent(qml_file_path)     

            
       gpkg_layer = self.iface.addVectorLayer(path_to_gpkg + "|layername=" + lyr, lyr, 'ogr')
       gpkg_layer.importNamedStyle(styledoc)
       
       self.offline_editing.synchronize()
```